# How to use a ContentProvider with DiskLruCache in Android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

In my Android app, I would like to cache images on disk that will then be displayed in a `WebView`, for which I need to access files by some kind of path or URI. (In order to use `<img src="..">`.) All caching implementations I found provide no access to the absolute file paths, but rather return `InputStreams` or `Bitmap` objects.

Is it possible to implement a `ContentProvider` that I can use to turn `Bitmap` objects into something file like by having `<img src="content://my/image.png">` in my `WebView`?

Comment: sure: override `ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(@NonNull Uri uri, @NonNull String mode)`

Comment: How do I get a ParcelFileDescriptor from a stream?

Comment: hmmm, what stream? your image is somewhere in your local file system, isn't it?

Comment: As indicated in the question, I would like to use a cache implementation that  returns only memory objects / streams and I have no indication of the actual file path.

Comment: see `ContentProvider#openPipeHelper`

Comment: or create a similar method if the way it uses `AsyncTask` is not really what you want (it uses `ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe` so you should use it as well and make your own producer part), [here](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/ContentProvider.java#1662) you have the sources

Comment: Hi, that seems promising! Why have I never seen that method? I will give it a try!

Comment: when writing from `PipeDataWriter` you can use `ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseOutputStream`

Comment: openPipeHelper works like a charm. If you phrase your comments as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

override `ContentProvider#openFile(Uri uri, String mode)`, if your content is in-memory cached data and you cannot return `ParcelFileDescriptor#open(File file, int mode)`, `ParcelFileDescriptor#fromFd(int fd)` or `ParcelFileDescriptor#fromSocket(Socket socket)` use a helper method `ContentProvider#openFileHelper(Uri uri, String mode)` or use `ParcelFileDescriptor#createPipe()` and implement your custom producer part

Comment: `openPipeHelper()` is what I ended up using, as you suggested in the comments above.